# Javascript does not call prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype, private

I try to override a method and script is:

```
function wrapper(target) {
    target.doABC = function () {
        alert('in wrapper');
    };
    return target;
}

function Model() {
    wrapper(this);
}

Model.prototype.doABC = function () {
    alert('in Model');
};

var a = new Model();
a.doABC();
```

The result is 'in wrapper'. I don't know why?

Comment: `Model` is an `object` and a `object` can not have 2 keys of same name!

Comment: @Rayon: `shadow`, not `override`, to use better terminology.  The OP isn't assigning a property to `Model` twice, he is assigning to `Model` and the prototype.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, True.. The term `override` will misinterpret things..

Answer (score 5):

Any JavaScript object has **own** and **inherited** properties. **Own** are those defined directly on the instance and **inherited** are taken from the `prototype` object.
When using a **property accessor**, JavaScript first searches in object's *own properties list*. If the property is not found, it searches in object's *prototype chain*.

In your example, the `wrapper()` method defines on object instance an own property `doABC`, which is a function that alerts `'in wrapper'`. Even if the object has a prototype with the same property `doAbc` that alerts `'in Model'`, JavaScript anyway will use the own property.

```
function wrapper(target) {
    // Define an own property "doABC"
    target.doABC = function () {
        alert('in wrapper');
    };
    return target;
}

function Model() {
    wrapper(this);
}

// Define an inherited property "doABC"
Model.prototype.doABC = function () {
    alert('in Model');
};

var a = new Model();

//Use the own property "doABC". The inherited "doABC" is ignored.
a.doABC();
```

As an addition, the own property can be removed using `delete` operator. After deletion, the object will use the inherited property.

```
// delete the own property "doABC"
delete a['doABC'];

// the inherited "doABC" will be used. Alerts "in Model"
a.doABC();
```

Check the complete [working demo](http://jsbin.com/kiyuqeq/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I tried to debug that script. Before run target.doABC statement, the object a already has doABC() method which comes from prototype. After ran target.doABC, this function is updated.

Comment: @user3468795 Yes, it happens this way in the constructor. My answer is for question `The result is 'in wrapper'. I don't know why?`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can explain:

You have two separate versions of `doABC` here.

Your `target.doABC` creates a function specific to  *that* instance of your `Model` and each `Model` get its own `doABC`.

Because `Model` has a `doABC`, the JavaScript engine has no need to look 'up the chain' for something else, hence it will never look for the `Model.prototype.doABC` version.

You can see this by adding these lines:

```
Model.prototype.doXYZ = function () {
    alert('in Model');
};
```

and calling

```
a.doXYZ();
```

Since `a` doesn't have its own `doXYZ` then, and only then, will it look up the chain and see the method in the prototype.